# How to use functions like repmat, replicate, or kron in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, matrix, repeat

I want to convert the matrix b:

```
b(:,:,1) =
     1
b(:,:,2) =
     3
b(:,:,3) =
     5
```

to matrix c:

```
c(:,:,1) =
     1     1
     1     1
c(:,:,2) =
     3     3
     3     3
c(:,:,3) =
     5     5
     5     5
```

without using `for` loops.
In matrix `c`, each `1x1` element of `b` is converted to a `2x2` block with the same value as the corresponding element in `b`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can just use indexing, which is usually quicker:

```
b([1 1],[1 1],:)
```

Comment: Excellent find! Very elegant!

Answer (score 3):

If I understand you correctly then:

```
   c = repmat(b, [2 2 1])
```